# Removing multiple scaling factors in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to place a single scaling factor in the top left corner, which seems to be default normally, instead of having factors of 10^n at every y axis tick.

In other words, I would like to format the y axis the same as the x axis as generated by the following script.

```
\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scaled y ticks=true,
    enlargelimits=false
]
\addplot+[only marks, mark=*,blue] coordinates {
(100000, 0.008)
(150000, 0.02)
(200000, 0.03)
(250000, 0.04)
(300000, 0.05)
(350000, 0.08)
(400000, 0.1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, upon reading the manual more closely, I realise this can be done with the

```
 scaled y ticks=base 10:2
```

option.

Comment: Thanks! I was futilely trying to determine how to add the axis multiplier to the y-axis when the y-values are small (i.e., on the order of hundreds), which `scaled y ticks=base 10:-2` achieves.